# What is form of derivative?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

Let $V$ is real vector space and $W_{t}$ is family of subspace in $V$ with same dimension. If $A_{t}$ is a family of linear map from $V$ to $W_{t}$ and $\gamma (t)$ is a curve on $V$ such that for all $t$ we have $\gamma (t) \in W_{t}$. What is the form of derivative of $ A_{t}(\gamma (t))$ from $t$?($t \in \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Is the domain of $\gamma$ the same as the indexing set of $A_t$ and $W_t$?

Comment: @R.Burton Yes, all of $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $W_t$ is a subspace of $V$, we can think of each $A_t$ as a linear transformation from $V$ into $V$; i.e as an element of $\rm Hom(V)$. So, we now have a map $A: \mathbb{R} \to \rm Hom(V)$, $t \mapsto A_t$. Also, we are given a map $\gamma : \Bbb{R} \to V$. With this, we can define the map $f: \Bbb{R} \to V$, by
\begin{equation}
f(t) = A_t[\gamma(t)]
\end{equation}
Now, you want to know about the derivative of $f$. If we assume that $A$ is differentiable, and $\gamma$ is also differentiable, then indeed $f$ will be differentiable, and we have the relation:
\begin{equation}
f'(t) = A'(t)[\gamma(t)] + A_t[\gamma'(t)].
\end{equation}
The equation above is a special case of the "generalised product rule". See for example Loomis and Sternberg's [Advanced Calculus](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~shlomo/docs/Advanced_Calculus.pdf), Chapter $3$, theorem $8.4$ for a statement and proof of this product rule.

Comment: thank you very much:)